# button event doesn't work properly

Tags: java

I have some doubts about the use of the methods wait() and notify(). I have the next code which has some button events, the first time the user pushes the button it has to stop printing, and the second time it restarts printing again. I understand that is better to use Runnable instead of Thread, but I have to use Thread because of the requirements. The code works fine the first time the button is pushed but the second time it doesn´t, I want to use the wait() and the notify, but i don´t know how to do it with this particular code.

```
class Thr extends Thread{
    private int count = 0;
    private long pause;
    private boolean canPrint = true;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    Thr(long miliseconds,JTextArea text){
        pause = miliseconds;
        textArea = text;
    }

    public void pushedButton(){
        if(canPrint)
           this.canPrint = false;
        else
            this.canPrint = true;

    }


    public void run()
    {
        while(this.canPrint)
        {
            try
            {
                this.printCounter();
                Thread.sleep(pause);
                this.count++;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    public void printCounter(){
        String time;
        time = Integer.toString(count);
        textArea.setText(time);  
    }
}

class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTextArea textArea,textArea2;
    private JButton button;
    private Thr thread,threadEvent;

    Interface()
    {
        textArea = new JTextArea(10,7);
        textArea2 = new JTextArea(10,7);
        thread = new Thr(2000,textArea);
        threadEvent = new Thr(1000,textArea2);
        button = new JButton("Pausar/Reanudar");
        this.getContentPane().add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea,BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea2,BorderLayout.EAST);

        thread.start();
        threadEvent.start();

        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        threadEvent.pushedButton();
    }       
}


public class MensajesHilos {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Interface i = new Interface();
        i.setTitle("Control Threads");
        i.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 240);
        i.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have coded, if you want to achieve the desired result,

I feel the modification need to be done in run method,

```
   public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(this.canPrint){
              try
              {
                this.printCounter();
                Thread.sleep(pause);
                this.count++;
              }
              catch(InterruptedException e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

in this way, your Thread will never go dead and toggle printing based on canPrint boolean value.

Also, make sure to declare canPrint variable `volatile`, so that changes to it will be directly written to main memory and reflected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

"*button event doesn´t work properly*"

This is false, if you put a print statement in the `actionPerformed` method, you will see that it is called every time you press the button.

By the way note that you can simplify this

```
if(canPrint)
   this.canPrint = false;
else
   this.canPrint = true;
```

To

```
this.canPrint = !this.canPrint;
```

Note that it is a good practice to always put `@Override` anotation on top of overriden method.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    threadEvent.pushedButton();
}
```

Now why don't you get the expected result ?

You ommit to call `thread.pushedButton`, so the `canPrint` will only be reseted in the `threadEvent` object, and will never be in `thread`.

Note that once the boolean are set to false, you will exit the `loop` and the process won't start back after even if you re-set the boolean value to `true`. This example will works using `while(true)` however, you should change the `true` to any sentinel value to handle the exit of the program as this will loop forever.

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(this.canPrint)
        {
                this.printCounter();
                this.count++;
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(pause);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that `pause` is never 0 else you will eat all of the computer process.

Note that, as other stated, you should declare variables that are accessed in thread as `volatile` (canPrint) in your case.